# How to highlight columns in an Altair heatmap?

Tags: python, altair

I would like to guide the reader's attention to just some columns (or rows and columns) in a heatmap, while still retaining the full context.

I can use `alt.condition` to alter color and opacity. Both work to some extent. But changes in opacity visualize in a similar way as changes in value. And using a different color changes the perception of values. What I would like to do instead is to put yellow or red borders around the consecutive columns I want to highlight.

This is what I have now. Any other ideas?

```py
    import altair as alt
    alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()
    
    def create_att_chart(df, keys_to_highlight=[], width=150, height=150, title=None, labels_x=True, labels_y=True):
        
        properties = {}
        if title:  
            properties['title'] = title  
         
        if width:  properties['width']  = width
        if height: properties['height'] = height
            
        chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
            x=alt.X('k:N', sort=None, axis=alt.Axis(labels=labels_x, title=None, ticks=False), title=None),
            y=alt.Y('q:N', sort=None, axis=alt.Axis(labels=labels_y, title=None, ticks=False), title=None),
            opacity=alt.Opacity('a:Q', legend=None),
            column=alt.Column('h:N', title=None, header=alt.Header(labels=False), spacing=0.), 
            row=   alt.Row(   'l:N', title=None, header=alt.Header(labels=False), spacing=5.))
            
        if keys_to_highlight:
            chart = chart.encode(
                color=alt.condition(
                    alt.Predicate(alt.FieldOneOfPredicate(field='k', oneOf=keys_to_highlight)),
                    alt.value('orange'),
                    alt.value('blue')))
        else:
            chart = chart.encode(color=alt.value('blue'))
        
        return chart.properties(**properties)

    [..]

    ((create_att_chart(df_pt, ['sage', '##maker'], title='Pre-Trained') | create_att_chart(df_ft, ['sage', '##maker'], title='Fine-Tuned', labels_y=False)).properties(padding=0))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try use the condition for the `stroke` encoding instead of `color`, but I think that would give you strokes around each box, which is probably not what you want. Instead you could use `mark_rule` or `mark_rect` with this example from the docs:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Compute x^2 + y^2 across a 2D grid
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(-5, 5), range(-5, 5))
z = x ** 2 + y ** 2
# Convert this grid to columnar data expected by Altair
source = pd.DataFrame({'x': x.ravel(), 'y': y.ravel(), 'z': z.ravel()})

heatmap = alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    y='y:O',
    color=alt.Color('z:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blues')))
```

Now add the rules:

```
rule1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_rule(stroke='orange', strokeWidth=2).encode(x=alt.value(20))
rule2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_rule(stroke='orange', strokeWidth=2).encode(x=alt.value(60))
heatmap + rule1 + rule2
```

[image]

A top rule might be more appealing/elegant and you could add text above it with mark_text if needed:

```
rule1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_rule(stroke='orange', strokeWidth=3).encode(
    y=alt.value(-5),
    x=alt.value(20),
    x2=alt.value(60))
heatmap + rule1
```

[image]

`mark_rect` works but add the lines in the middle of squares since the scale is ordinal and a quantitative mark_rect messes up the axis:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0], 'x2': [3]})
box = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect(color='', stroke='orange', strokeWidth=2).encode(
    x='x:O',
    x2=alt.X2('x2:O', title='x'))
heatmap + box
```

[image]

If you try to add the lines in between, new ordinal axis marks will be created. You could abuse this and make the lines white to highlight by separation but the ticks on the axis are still there, so you would have to remove them with `lablExpr` or similar.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.5], 'x2': [3.5]})
box = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect(color='', stroke='white').encode(
    x='x:O',
    x2=alt.X2('x2:O', title='x'))
(heatmap + box).configure_view(stroke=None)
```

[image]

Comment: These are great options. I also like the new suggestion with the horizontal rule a lot. It looks more refined, less in your face. I tried implementing it, but when "adding" the rule to the chart  (in the example above) I get the error message: "ValueError: Faceted charts cannot be layered. " :(

Comment: @MarianoKamp Yeah for the time being, it is not possible to layer faceted charts i n Vega-Lite, but you can facet layer charts. So if you switch the other of the operations it should be fine (as long as you want to highlight the same columns in each facet, which seems to be the case from your image)